# return last message from grouped messages SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql tables one which has users and the other which has messages.

Right now my query is:

```
SELECT messages.*, username FROM messages
JOIN users ON messages.from_ID = users.user_ID
WHERE to_ID = 19
GROUP BY thread_ID
ORDER BY msg_ID DESC;
```

Entity(messages):

```
msg_ID
from_ID
to_ID
subject
message
date
```

Right now, it is returning **FIRST** message where `to_ID = 19`. What I want to do is show the **LATEST** message ordered by the highest `msg_ID`. I can do a `order by` on it but my sql statement only returns one row so I have to do something before it reaches the `group by` statement.

If these are the two rows eligible to be returned:

```
msg_ID from_ID to_ID subject message date thread_id username
15  26  19  Hey testing string2 1477750565 1 testing
17  26  19  Hey testing string. 1477750594 1 testing
```

My current result:

```
msg_ID from_ID to_ID subject message date thread_id username  
15  26  19  Hey testing string2 1477750565 1 testing
```

What I want:

```
msg_ID from_ID to_ID subject message date thread_id username  
17  26  19  Hey testing string. 1477750594 1 testing // msg_ID is higher here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this by *selecting* the correct message, not by using aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT m.*, u.username
FROM messages m JOIN
     users u
     ON m.from_ID = u.user_ID
WHERE m.to_ID = 19 AND
      m.msg_id = (SELECT MAX(m2.msg_id)
                  FROM messages m2
                  WHERE m2.thread_id = m.thread_id AND m2.to_ID = m.to_ID
                 )
ORDER BY msg_ID DESC;
```